# Is this claim valid as a proof?

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion, solution-verification

I have a function $g(x)$ and I need to prove that $\; g(x)-x g'(x)\neq0$ on domain $0<x<a$, where $a$ is a real positive number. Using Taylor series for the mentioned expression around $x=0$, we obtain $ \; g(x)-x g'(x)=a x^3+O(x^5)$. So, does this mean that $\; g(x)-x g'(x)$ is always non-zero over the domain $(0,a)$? Can it be considered as a proof?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a proof, since any constant possible could be contained in the $O$, and thus $O(x^5)$ can be arbitrarily large on $(0,a)$. Namely, it can be equal to $ax^3$ wherever we want it to be.

Comment: Thanks. That is true. This is the exact expression on the rhs : $8 \pi  a^2 x^3-\frac{16}{3} \pi  a^2 \left(3 a^2+\pi ^2\right) x^5$. And therefore, as you said it might be zero for some $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is true but not at all the interval $(0,a)$, it is true at a certain neighborwohood of $ 0$.

$$(\forall x\in (0,a))\; g(x)-xg'(x)=ax^3+O(x^5)\implies $$

$$(\forall x\in (0,a)) g(x)-xg'(x)=ax^3(1+x\epsilon(x))$$
with $$\lim_{x\to 0,x\ne 0}\epsilon(x)=0$$

For $ x $ close to zero, $ -\frac 12<x\epsilon(x)<\frac 12$, thus

$$(\exists \eta>0)\;: (\forall x\in (0,\eta))$$
$$g(x)-xg'(x)=ax^3(1+x\epsilon(x))>\frac{ax^3}{2}>0$$

Comment: This is the exact expression on the rhs : $8 \pi  a^2 x^3-\frac{16}{3} \pi  a^2 \left(3 a^2+\pi ^2\right) x^5$. And therefore, as Milo said above it might be zero for some $x$.

Comment: @Mariya The term in $x^5$ is negligeable in front if the term in $ x^3)$ so, only the coefficient of $x^3) will be taken into account near near zeeo.

Comment: But the question is not about small values of $x$. It could be a large number.

Comment: You should look at how we do to know the position of the tangent line or the asymptote and the curve.

Comment: @Mariya I said it is not true for any $a>0$ , it is only true for Some $\eta>0$ small enough.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it is true for small values of $a$, but I need to prove it for general $a$.